# C++ - Error Conversion from const char* to char*

Tags: c++

I am having an issue receiving this error when compiling code similar to the below.
I am getting this error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive].

I am unsure why as the strchr function accepts const char* ? maybe I am confused here. I have looked at other people having this same error on this site but I still don't see the solution clearly.

People had mentioned UNION? I have no clue how to use this keyword and was wondering if I could get clarification.

Could someone explain why this is happening or how is the safest/best method to resolving this error? I have other errors just like this in other spots in my code in the same situation.

```
#include <strings.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    validURL ('www.why_CPP_hates_me.com');
    return 0;
}

bool validURL (const char *url)
{
    char *q = strchr (url, '?');
    ...
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Read about [`std::strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr) and then read the error message again. The problem is not that `std::strchr` takes a `const char *`, it's that it returns a `const char *` and you can't assign it to a `char *` because that would lose the `const`. Use `const char *q` instead.

Comment: Note that the confusion may come from how in c [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) takes `const char*` and returns `char*`.

Comment: Also you need to use `"` instead of `'` for strings.

Comment: You must be getting a different error, because you're not passing anything that can be converted to `const char*` to `validURL`.

Comment: To validate a URL you might need a regular expression to do it. This looks really superficial.

Comment: @nwp thanks this worked for me. I misunderstood the site I was reading explaining the strchr or maybe I was looking at the C version and just assumed it was the same.

Comment: @tadman haha yea this is just a check against existing templates I am modifying someone's existing code they did not use reg ex. Thanks tho! If I have to rebuild from stratch I will look that route.

Comment: You are trying to use C function with C++, among other things. Here it is working fine when compiled in C https://ideone.com/IS0rhz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to this is:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

bool validURL(const char *url);  // Must forward declare or prototype the 
                                // function before calling

int main()
{
    validURL("www.why_CPP_hates_me.com"); // Single quotes are for single chars
                                          // Double quotes are for string 
                                          // literals, which create a const char*
    return 0;
}

bool validURL(const char *url)
{
    const char *q = strchr(url, '?'); // You have to assign to a const char*
                                      // to maintain const correctness.
                                      // strchr() has const char* and char* 
                                      // overloads. But you have to assign to
                                      // the correct type.

    return true;
}
```

Or if you wanted to you could do this:

```
bool validURL(const char *url)
{
    char *q = strchr(const_cast<char*>(url), '?');
    // Casting away const is not recommended generally. Should be careful.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Casting away `const` from a top-level `const` object is just asking for UB. Would not recommend.

Comment: Yeah definitely, I'll add that it's not recommended.

Comment: "Must forward declare" Is a bit strong. You can also place the function definition ahead of first use. Personally I don't like unnecessary prototypes because they're more lines of code that can be wrong.

Comment: @user4581301 Do you mean declaring the function without the name of the argument?

Comment: @user4581301 Is there a difference between prototyping the function and forward declaring? I thought they were the same thing. Is the difference the name of the parameter/argument?

Comment: @Zebrafish To put it concisely: A function must be delcared before calling it. Whether that declaration it was a *forward* declaration or a definition is inconsequential.

Comment: I mean discard the forward declaration and put the function ahead of `main`. That way when you change the function to `bool validURL(const string & url)` you don't have to make the change in two places or face linker/compiler errors.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah, I see.

Comment: @user4581301 there is a good argument for using a forward declarations for all functions: If you forward declare all functions first, and then define them, then you don't need to care about the order of declarations or about the order of definitions at all. If you define all functions in first declaration, then you need to sort them in order of dependency. Complexity of sorting is a O(N log N), while partitioning declarations and definitions is O(N), so partitioning scales better for big code bases :)

Comment: I have to agree with that. Someone tripped over that problem yesterday and got infinite recursion as a result. Compiler or linker error would have been easier to sort out. Manually maintaining the forward declarations is a nuisance though. If you can automatically generate them as part of the build process, do it. Kills both problems. Assuming your code generator works correctly.

Comment: Complexity of sorting should be mitigated by writing the functions in a nice, testable order in the first place. If you need function X to implement function Y, you should have written and tested function X first. Be nice to live in a predicable, perfect world where you could do that, wouldn't it?